# Target logic based on Widget / Sidebar Name

Tags: widgets, sidebar

I have a theme that uses registers a sidebar called 'homepage-middle-widget' and it's child widgets are pulling images in undesired sizes. Is it possible to target a widget and / or it's parent in PHP? I was thinking something like:

```
if (is_home() && widget_name == 'foo-widget' && sidebar_name == 'homepage-middle-widget'): 
/*run this code*/; 
else: /*run default code*/;
endif;
```

I can't seem to find anything in the codex about targeting specific sidebar names or widgets by placement.

The alternative would be writing a new widget, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the logic inside widget functions. When the widget is added in sidebar, it will check for sidebar name and home page.

```
   global $wp_registered_widgets, $wp_registered_sidebars;
   $sidebars_widgets = get_option('sidebars_widgets');
   if($sidebars_widgets["sidebar-1"] && is_home()) 
   {
      //Write your logic here
   }
```